# If $G$ is a simple, connected graph with no loops or cycles, then it has at least two vertices with degree 1.

Tags: graph-theory

**Question:**

> Prove the statement:
>
> If $G$ is a  connected graph with no cycles, then it has at least two vertices with degree 1.

This seems pretty obvious, as if the graph has no cycles then it must have 2 "endpoints" which must have degree $1$, but obviously enough this is nothing quite like a proof.

E: The question didn't actually said the graph had no loops or that it was simple, I accidentally added that in.

Comment: Are you able to show that there is at least one?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to.

Comment: I have posted an answer below.

Comment: This claim isn't true for the graph with a single vertex and no edges, or for the graph that contains no vertices. It's a silly technicality, but this should be stated.

Comment: Re your edit: I think a loop and a double-edge count as cycles of length $1$ and $2$ respectively. If not, then the result is false (e.g., two vertices with $m\geq 2$ edges between them would be a counterexample)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, we assume that the graph has at least two vertices.

Choose a vertex $v$ at random.  For a general vertex, $w$, define $L_v(w)$ to be the length of a minimal path connecting $v$ to $w$ and let $N$ be a vertex for which this length is maximal.  Then we claim that $N$ has degree $1$.  To see this, suppose it were false.  Then $N$ would have some edge emanating from it, other than the one used in the path connecting it to $v$.  Suppose that edge connected $N$ to $P$.  We know that $L_v(P)≤L_v(N)$ by the construction of $N$, from which it follows that there is a path connecting $P$ to $v$ which is different from the obvious one which flows through $N$.  It then follows that there is a cycle in the graph, contrary to assumption.

In this way, we have produced one point, $N$ of degree 1.  To get another, repeat the process, starting from the vertex $N$. (this is where we use the assumption that the graph has more than one vertex.  If there is just one vertex, then this second stage would just produce $N$ again).

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_1$ be a vertex, and assume that all the other vertices have degree greater than one. Since the graph is connected, there is a vertex $u_2$ that has degree $\geq2$ and is adjacent to $u_1$. Similarly, we find a vertex $u_3\neq u_1$ adjacent to $u_2$, and so on. Since the graph is finite, it happens that $u_i=u_j$, for some $i\neq j$. In other words, we get a cycle, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a **superGraph** to be simple, connected graph with no loops or cycles. This is because I don't want to have to repeat the phrase "*simple, connected graph with no loops or cycles*" over and over.

Firstly, this claim isn't true for a superGraph with $0$ or $1$ vertices. It is pretty clearly true for the single possible graph with two vertices.

Suppose that the claim is true for any superGraph on $n-1$ vertices for $n>2$. Consider any arbitrary superGraph $G$ on $n$ vertices and note that it can be constructed by adding a vertex $v$ and some number of edges on $v$ to a superGraph on $n-1$ vertices. This number of edges on $v$ cannot be $0$ because $G$ is connected. This number of edges on $v$ also cannot be be greater than $1$ because that would create a cycle, so $v$ has degree $1$. Note then that since we are adding a degree $1$ vertex to a graph with at least two degree $1$ vertices, the resulting graph $G$ must have at least two degree $1$ vertices. $_{\square}$

Comment: I could follow most, until the part "the number of edges added can't be greater than 1 because that would create a cycle". Why is that?

Comment: Suppose we add vertex $v$ of degree $2$ so that $v$ is adjacent to vertices $a$ and $b$. Since the original graph that we are adding $v$ to is connected, there is some path between $a$ and $b$. The cycle we create would consist of this path between $a$ and $b$ plus the edges $\{v,a\}$ and $\{v,b\}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was gonna accept your answer but I realized I had copied the question wrongly.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I don't think that you edit changes anything. See [Casteels](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/92730/casteels)' comment on your post.

Comment: "Consider any arbitrary superGraph G on n vertices and note that it can be constructed by adding a vertex v and some number of edges on v to a superGraph on n−1 vertices."

How? This seems like a pretty circular approach - you need to show that there's a vertex, such that if you remove it, you still have a superGraph -> still a connected graph. That's going to require that this vertex is of degree 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that simple, connected graphs with no loops or cycles (AKA *trees*) with $n$ vertices have $n-1$ edges, then by the Handshaking Lemma, you have $$\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v) = 2n-2.$$ If $n\geq 2$, then $\deg(v)\geq 1$ for every vertex $v$, but now notice that the equation can only be satisfied if at least two summands on the left are exactly $1$.